# How to remove HTML div on click using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So I have this `Display()` function which takes events from the Google Calendar and the function returns a list of elements (each element is associated with a slider) to be rendered on the screen (see return statement of `Display()` function) and renders them as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qLmK.png). So each element comes with a `Remove` button so that I can remove an unwanted element from the page using the `hideMe()` function inside the `Display()` function. The `hideMe()` function does seem to do its work, however, it removes all the elements on the page as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wORMe.png). So I am struggling to figure out what I should fix so that when I click on the `Remove` button, it only removes the element and the slider associated to that `remove` button. I am new to React and JavaScript so please help. Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance.

```
function Display() {
    const isMounted = useRef(true);
    const [items, saveItems] = useState([]);
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);
    const [fading, setFading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            isMounted.current = false;
        };
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const items = await fetchItems();
            //Do not update state if component is unmounted
            if (isMounted.current) {
                saveItems(items);
            }
        })();
    }, []);

    function hideMe() {
        setFading(true);
        setTimeout(() => setVisible(false), 650);
    }

    return (
        <Tab.Pane attached={false}>
            <h5>Rate stress level for each event</h5>
            <br/>
            {items.map(item => (
                    <div key={item.id} isvisible={!fading}
                         style={visible ? null : { display: "none" }}>
                        <Typography id="discrete-slider-restrict" gutterBottom>
                           {item}
                           <button onClick={hideMe}>Remove</button>
                        </Typography>
                        <PrettoSlider aria-label="pretto slider" defaultValue={98} step={null}marks={stresslevel}/>
                    </div>
            ))}
        </Tab.Pane>
    )
}
```

Comment: can you try to add a fiddle example here, so that we can easily debug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that this issue is happening because all elements are available in same state or i would say that they all share same state. So, this executes for all. If it is possible for you to extract it to a new component and use the hideMe function there. This will i am sure work for each individual elements.

It is my suggestion please go through below. May be you have to tweak a little bit.

You can extract the elements in a separate component like:

```
const Item = props => {

     const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);
     const [fading, setFading]   = useState(false);

     function hideMe() {
         setFading(true);
         setTimeout(() => setVisible(false), 650);
     }

     return (
         <div isvisible={!fading} style={visible ? null : { display: "none" }}>
            <Typography id="discrete-slider-restrict" gutterBottom>
                  {item}
               <button onClick={hideMe}>Remove</button>
            </Typography>
            <PrettoSlider aria-label="pretto slider" defaultValue={98} 
                          step={null} marks={stresslevel}/>
         </div>
     );

};
export default Item;
```

Then you can use it like:

```
  // import Item
{items.map(item => (
    <Item key={item.id} itemObj={item} /> 
    // in case if you need item obj then props.itemObj will get you the object.
))}
```

---

In this way you can manage the `hideMe` function with the separate specific Item component.